# Why is the properties option greyed out in the XFCE panel icon menu?

Tags: xfce, menu

I'm using XFCE and I'm trying to change the properties on a panel icon. However, the option for properties on that icon is greyed out. For some reason it's only for that icon, the other icons are fine. Here is a cropped screenshot to show what I mean.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be that you already have the properties dialog open somewhere for that menu item and have lost track of it. Look around your workspaces for an open instance of the properties dialog window. ;)